# Where to get the latest GCC (GNU C Compiler)

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, gcc

Currently my version is 4.8.4 but Ive found that some sites offer a 4.9 version. like this http://gcc.igor.onlinedirect.bg/snapshots

But where do they get the source from? I want to know so I can be sure I really have the latest version

because of rep limits I cant answer my question here so I edited my question:

I finally found it! :D

ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots

Comment: About how long will compiling take on 1x2GHz Athlon Venice cpu and 2GB RAM?

Comment: comments are intended for clarification of the original post, not for additional ones.

Comment: @guntbert If i asked as normal then someone would probably put it on hold?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the latest source code form [the SVN repository](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html). You can [browse the SVN history online](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/) to see the latest commits.

The sites that provide snapshots simply build the binaries from SVN trunk at regular intervals, usually a few times a day. To always have the latest available version you would have to compile from SVN after every single commit, which is even more often.

Unless you want to contribute to GCC however, it is **not** recommended to use the development version and you should use the latest stable release.

Comment: Thanks this would be better because it shows not only the gcc but other gnu programs if I could download it (there is no download option in google chrome 35).

Comment: I would upvote you but my rep is too low (It says I need 15 rep to upvote)

Comment: I can upvote now! Have my upvote :D